# How to display taxonomy parent for selected taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy

I want to show on the site the parent of the selected taxonomy. For that I have the above code but the problem with this is that it is showing all the selected taxonomy in a list with now structure.

```
global $post;
$features = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'property-feature' );

if ( !empty( $features ) && is_array( $features ) && !is_wp_error( $features ) ) {
?>
<div class="property-features">
    <?php
    global $inspiry_options;
    $property_features_title = $inspiry_options[ 'inspiry_property_features_title' ];
    if( !empty( $property_features_title ) ) {
        ?><h4 class="fancy-title"><?php echo esc_html( $property_features_title ); ?></h4><?php
    }
    ?>
    <ul class="property-features-list clearfix">
        <?php

        foreach( $parent_term as $single_feature ) {
            echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $single_feature->slug, 'property-feature' ) .'">'. $single_feature->name . '</a></li>';
        }
        ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php
```

}

Example:

Parent: option 1, option 2

Parent 2 : option 3, option 4

If I select option 2 and option 3 I want to see

Parent: option 2

Parent 2 : option 3

Updare 2

```
  global $post;
$features = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'property-feature' );
$featuresss = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'property-feature' );

// determine the topmost parent of a term
function get_term_top_most_parent($term_id, $taxonomy){
    // start from the current term
    $parent  = get_term_by( 'id', $term_id, $taxonomy);
    // climb up the hierarchy until we reach a term with parent = '0'
    while ($parent->parent != '0'){
        $term_id = $parent->parent;

        $parent  = get_term_by( 'id', $term_id, $taxonomy);
    }
    return $parent;
}

// so once you have this function you can just loop over the results returned by wp_get_object_terms

function hey_top_parents($taxonomy, $results = 1) {
    // get terms for current post
    $terms = wp_get_object_terms( get_the_ID(), $taxonomy );
    $y = get_the_terms($terms->term_id, $taxonomy);
    // set vars
    $top_parent_terms = array();
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        //get top level parent
        $top_parent = get_term_top_most_parent( $term->term_id, $taxonomy );
        //check if you have it in your array to only add it once
        if ( !in_array( $top_parent, $top_parent_terms ) ) {
            $top_parent_terms[] = $top_parent;
        }
    }
    // build output (the HTML is up to you)
        foreach( $top_parent_terms as $single_feature ) {
                echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $single_feature->slug, 'property-feature' ) .'">'. $single_feature->name . '</a></li>';
                foreach( $terms as $single ) {
                    echo '<ul><li><a href="' . get_term_link( $single->slug, 'property-feature' ) .'">'. $single->name . '</a></li></ul>';
                }
            }

    //return $top_parent_terms;

}
```

I managed to display the top parent for the selected taxonomy but now the problem is that I need now to display in the top parent anly the selected taxonomy from that parent

Answer (score 3):

```
global $post;
$taxonomy = "property-feature";

// determine the topmost parent of a term
function get_term_top_most_parent($term_id, $taxonomy){
    // start from the current term
    $parent  = get_term_by( 'id', $term_id, $taxonomy);
    // climb up the hierarchy until we reach a term with parent = '0'
    while ($parent->parent != '0'){
        $term_id = $parent->parent;

        $parent  = get_term_by( 'id', $term_id, $taxonomy);
    }
    return $parent;
}

// so once you have this function you can just loop over the results returned by wp_get_object_terms

function hey_top_parents($taxonomy, $results = 1) {
    // get terms for current post
    $terms = wp_get_object_terms( get_the_ID(), $taxonomy );

    // set vars
    $top_parent_terms = array();
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        //get top level parent
        $top_parent = get_term_top_most_parent( $term->term_id, $taxonomy );
        //check if you have it in your array to only add it once
        if ( !in_array( $top_parent, $top_parent_terms ) ) {
            $top_parent_terms[] = $top_parent;
        }
    }
    // build output (the HTML is up to you)
    foreach( $top_parent_terms as $single_feature ) 
    {
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $single_feature->slug, $taxonomy ) .'">'. $single_feature->name . '</a></li>';

        foreach( $terms as $single ) {
            if( $single_feature->term_id == $single->parent ) {
                echo '<ul><li><a href="' . get_term_link( $single->slug, $taxonomy ) .'">'. $single->name . '</a></li></ul>';
            }
        }
    }

    //return $top_parent_terms;
}
```

**CHANGES:**

1) Moved taxonomy name to variable (used in echo's).

```
$taxonomy = "property-feature";
```

2) Added if condition to the code responsible for displaying sub terms.

```
    if( $single_feature->term_id == $single->parent ) {
        echo '<ul><li><a href="' . get_term_link( $single->slug, $taxonomy ) .'">'. $single->name . '</a></li></ul>';
    }
```

**REMOVED (not used lines of codes):**

1)

```
$features = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'property-feature' );
$featuresss = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'property-feature' );
```

2)

```
$y = get_the_terms($terms->term_id, $taxonomy);
```

**CONSIDER:**

1) Removing $results variable from:

```
function hey_top_parents($taxonomy, $results = 1) {
```

it is not used anywhere or maybe should be to determine if results should be returned or displayed by the function.

Comment: Use $taxonomy = "property-feature"; as arg while calling function hey_top_parents

Comment: How do I use this functions ?